# Gradle properties in 2.6 vs 2.7

Tags: gradle

If I specify in 'build.gradle' that belongs to the root:

```
allprojects {
    version="1.0-SNAPSHOT" 
}
```

Then I want to use the same version property in a subproject like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.myproject.module', name: 'first', version: allprojects.version
}
```

In Gradle 2.6: it will put '[1.0-SNAPSHOT]'

In Gradle 2.7: it will be '1.0-SNAPSHOT' without brackets

What can be the reason for that? Is that due to some gradle issues in 2.6? In gradle 2.2.1 - it also works fine. Maybe you could recommend some best practices here?

Answer (score 0):

answer can be found here (I posted the same question on gradle forum): https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-properties-in-2-6-vs-2-7/11919